# Multiple tables with the same name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

when running the query below, I get a duplicate table returned, even though only one of it exists. Why could that be?

```
SELECT 
s.Name AS SchemaName,
t.NAME AS TableName,
p.rows AS RowCounts,
SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
(SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
INNER JOIN      
sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
TotalSpaceKB DESC
```

** UPDATE
The database name was displayed with a (In Recovery) tag, I just ran a script to check and it said that it is 11% completed.  Could this also have caused this problem?

Comment: it's not returning any duplicates the same query i'm executing

Comment: i did not get any duplicates when running this query

Comment: You probably have multiple entries in the `sys.partitions` table for the duplicated tables.

Comment: It is not supposed to, but about an hour ago it started returning duplicates on my DB.  I just want to know if this indicates that something in the background is happening.

Comment: Did you recently add any indexes?

Comment: I added two indexes today actually, is that what's causing this?

Comment: Yes you are selecting from sys.indexes. If there are more than 1 index you will get a row for each index.

Comment: This happened on a bulk insert, is there any way that I can revert these changes? (The DB is terribly slow right now to the point of not being able to change or select anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sean pointed out, you have more than one index on the duplicated tables. To check the index name(s) you can run the slightly modified query:

```
SELECT 
t.NAME AS TableName,
s.Name AS SchemaName,
p.rows AS RowCounts,
i.name,
SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
(SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows, i.name
ORDER BY 
    t.name
```